# How to CONCATENATE js and angularjs expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am redirecting to another page using onClick js function. But I want to include query string to the given URL. The query string consists of an ID which I am getting from angularjs expression. I am having trouble in combining the two expressions.

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 padding10 left-border" onclick="window.location=RootURL+'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID=83'">{{x.MemberPosition}}</div>
```

In the above code, I want to replace cID= 83 to something like cID= x.ContestID. I am getting the value of {{x.ContestID}} correctly.

Comment: try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28536641/454869 It will work and you view will look better

Comment: yup, I am trying ur solution now.

Comment: Tell us about results. If any answer was useful, please, vote and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to do it this way

### Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.constant('RootUrl', function() {
    return '/';
});

app.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'RootUrl' function($scope, $location, RootUrl) {
    $scope.gotoContest = function(id) {
        var url = RootUrl + 'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID=' + id;
        $location.url(url);
    };
}]);
```

### View:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 padding10 left-border" ng-click="gotoContest(x.ContestID)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), you should use `$window`  instead of `window`

> A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally
>   available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is
>   a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the
>   $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for
>   testing

Or `$location` instead of `window.location`

> The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based
>   on window.location) and makes the URL available to your application.
>   Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into the $location
>   service and changes to $location are reflected into the browser
>   address bar.

BTW, if you want to use `$location` in the view directly, remember to bind `$location` to the controller's scope like

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$location= $location;
});
```

Comment: In the current scenario, should I use ng-click = "$window.href = RootURL+'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID={{x.ContestID}}"?

Comment: check my update. `window.location`'s Angular replacement is `$location`, so you can change it to `ng-click ="$location.path(RootURL+'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID=' + x.ContestID)"`

Comment: I have implemented, <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 padding10 left-border" ng-click="$location.path(RootURL+'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID={{x.ContestID}})‌​">. I also declared $location variable in controller. But I am getting an error.

Comment: does it work now? I suppose we don't need double brackets in `ng-click`.

Comment: I also tried it without brackets but it still gives an error. `Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2023-77%20%5B'pages%2Fcontest%2Fcontestdetail.ui.php%3FcID%3Dx.ContestID)%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%5D&p2=%24location.path(RootURL%2B'pages%2Fcontest%2Fcontestdetail.ui.php%3FcID%3Dx.ContestID)%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B
T/<@http://localhost:8080/sportscash/scripts/angular_1.3.8.min.js:6:416`

Comment: can you show me your html code of this element? seems this is caused by mixing usage of `'` and `"`

Comment: Of course, there is an unmatched quote. Should be `"$location.path(RootURL+'pages/contest/contestdetail.ui.php?cID={{x.Con‌​testID}}')‌​"`. But I'm not shure that this will work as you want

Comment: nope, still the same error. Now I am trying to call an angular function on ng-click.

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer Sorry, did not mention main error: you should use `$location.url()` method instead of `$location.path()`